# Azure Cosmos DB Mongo - choosing partition key for a customers repository

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a requirement to create a repository for user information, which will hold a couple of million records, using CosmosDb (Mongo).

Looking at user information, I don't find a property that allows even distribution along partitions. The only property that seems to be fair is the userID itself (Guid). Besides, most of write and read operations are based on that userID so it seems to be a good candidate.

So this would lead me to a couple of million of logical partitions. Operations with partition key are fine, but I also have other read operations that will result in fan-out queries.

My struggle is here - what are the drawbacks of partitioning with userId for query operations, and if is there any way of using some sort of index to overcome performance issues with these operations?

One thing not sure if makes any difference, each logical partition will hold only one document, not sure if this helps for these queries..

I'm quite new at this, sorry if questions are not raised the best way!